# play an extract of a sound file

Tags: qt, audio, pyqt

I'm working on Python3, Qt4/Qt5 project and I'm stuck with the problem of playing an extract from a sound file, something like "play from 1.32 to 2.25 seconds". From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsound.html) QSound class doesn't allow to do so. Am I right ? Should I try using [Phonon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861592/play-sound-file-in-pyqt) by example ?

I have the possibility to slice my main file into several small files (by example, 1_32__2_25.wav) but I want to be sure there is no other possibility.

P.S. : Phonon [isn't available anymore in Qt 5.2](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/37616).

Comment: As you've already suggested, there isn't going to be a _single_ solution that works with both Qt4 and Qt5. Also, you should state which platform(s) this has to work on.

Comment: Let's say I'm using Qt5 for this project : Googie's solution (see infra) seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QMediaPlayer` and its `setPosition()` method.